# Universal query to check whether a table exist in all RDBMS

Tags: java, mysql, sql, oracle, h2

I have searched a lot but i could not find a query which will apply to any RDBMS to check whether a table exits. Some are ok with mysql and h2 but its not compatible with oracle. Any one has a solution for this.

This works for oracle but not h2 or mysql

```
select count(*) as tblCount from user_tables where table_name = 'ALERTS_HISTORY';
```

Answer (score 3):

The `java.sql.DatabaseMetaData` object (which is obtainable from a `Connection` via `.getMetaData()` has a `getTables(…)` function, which does what you want; the driver will care about the SQL.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just check your solution with oracle db ..Following is the code.                                     ResultSet rs=databaseMetaData.getTables(null,null,tableName,null);
            Boolean tableExist=false;
            if (rs.next()) {
                tableExist=true;
            }                                                                    Table is exist in my schema but it won't go inside the if statement. Is there a mistake i have done?

Comment: also when use with h2 with same parameters i'm getting e = {org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException@9977}"org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column TYPE_NAME not found; I'm only sending the table name as a parameter. is there some more to send like catalog ,schema etc

Comment: AFAIK, some oracle drivers do not like to allow table requests without catalog. Also which version of h2 are you using? The error may well be a bug in their JDBC implementation.

Comment: @dnWick: don't forget that Oracle tables are stored in uppercase. So you have to supply the name in uppercase as well. `getTables()` *does* work with Oracle if you provide the parameters properly. You should also provide the schema (=user) name to avoid getting tables from other users with that call